# Why is this JSON variable undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I've got the following code.

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
function postUser() {
    var user = $('span input').serialize;
    alert(user.username);
}
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<span>
  User name : <input type="text" name="username"><br />
  Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
  First name: <input type="text" name="firstName" /><br />
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName" /><br />

  <button onclick="postUser()">Submit</button>
</span>
```

When I populate the  items in the UI, the alert says "undefined" - but I thought by serializing the array it should be a JSON object?  Any ideas why username is undefined?

Comment: Don't alert. Use your browser's console with `console.log(user)`.

Comment: Well, to start you're not calling `serialize()`

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You forgot the `()` in order to call the function.

```
var user = $('span input').serialize();
```

---

Furthermore, `.serialize()` gives you a `string` result, not an object.

Perhaps you wanted this instead:

```
var username = $('span input[name=username]').val();
```

---

If you want an object that references all the values, you'll need to make it.

```
var vals = {};

$('span input').each(function() {
    vals[this.name] = this.value;
});

var name = vals.username;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need [serialize](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) here.

What you need is to get the value of the input whose name is "username" :

```
alert($('input[name="username"]').val());
```

Comment: thank you, the reason it was serialize before was because I was then posting the result, so I debugged it to the point the post wasn't working so I made an alert, overlooking the fact I'd missed the ()

Answer (score 0):

.serialize() is used to encode a set of form elements as *a string* for submission. It does not allow you to access form values as an object. [Read more](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/)

HTML

```
<span>
  User name : <input type="text" name="username"><br />
  Password: <input type="password" name="password" /><br />
  First name: <input type="text" name="firstName" /><br />
  Last name: <input type="text" name="lastName" /><br />

  <button id="btn" onclick="postUser()">Submit</button>
</span>​
```

Jquery

```
$("#btn").click(function(){
   alert($('input[name="username"]').val());
 });
```

[Try the demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZ8gj/1/)